# hibernate3:hbm2ddl goal no jdbc connection

Tags: hbm2ddl, hibernate3, hibernate3-maven-plugin

I am trying to create the ddl script for my application which uses hibernate-3.4.0.GA. Here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.apprick.webservice</groupId>
<artifactId>apprickwebapp</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>webapp Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<dependencies>

    <!-- MySQL database driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.21</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Hibernate library dependecy start -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate library dependecy end -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <components>
                    <component>
                        <name>hbm2ddl</name>
                        <implementation>annotationconfiguration</implementation>
                    </component>
                </components>
                <componentProperties>
                    <drop>true</drop>
                    <configurationfile>src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml</configurationfile>
                </componentProperties>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                    <version>5.1.8</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
    <finalName>webapp</finalName>
</build>
</project>
```

Since i am using hibernate 3.4.0-GA the whole project is annotation based so there are no persistence.xml in my project. The hibernate.cfg.xml file is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
    <!-- <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/apprick_db</property> -->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">rsingh</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">welcome</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <!-- <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property> -->
    <mapping class="com.apprick.common.User"></mapping>
    <mapping class="com.apprick.common.Customer"></mapping>
    <mapping class="com.apprick.common.ApprickAdmin"></mapping>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Now when i run mvn hibernate3:hbm2ddl i get the following exception

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The user must supply a JDBC connection
at org.hibernate.connection.UserSuppliedConnectionProvider.getConnection(UserSuppliedConnectionProvider.java:54)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.ManagedProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(ManagedProviderConnectionHelper.java:52)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:252)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:211)
at org.codehaus.mojo.hibernate3.exporter.Hbm2DDLExporterMojo.doExecute(Hbm2DDLExporterMojo.java:112)
at org.codehaus.mojo.hibernate3.HibernateExporterMojo.execute(HibernateExporterMojo.java:152)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
```

Can anyone please suggest me a solution for it. I have been trying to get this done since last two days and its totally driving me crazy.

Thanks for reading the post and i appreciate your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you figured it out by now. But in case you have not here is a hint:

the part

```
<componentProperties>
   <drop>true</drop>
   <configurationfile>src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml</configurationfile>
</componentProperties>
```

is wrong because you specify the full path

```
<configurationfile>hibernate.cfg.xml</configurationfile>
```

is enough, provided the file hibernate.cfg.xml is located in you root Classpath (i.e. WEB-INF/classes)